# Exploding a solid object

Tags: physics

I've been trying to make a cube explode without gravity in a solid form.  Just fragments, no fire or smoke.  I've watched every video I could find but I just can't get it to work...quick explode is great, but it seems to just throw paper thin pieces, not big chunks.  Anyway, if someone could post a step-by-step procedure that would be awesome.  Sorry if I'm missing the obvious.

[blender file](http://[%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=935%22%20/%3E](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/935/))

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing this is with cell fracture and adding rigid body physics. Add a cube to your scene and <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *edit mode* and press <kbd>W</kbd>*>subdivide* and subdivide it a few times to give it some more geometry. Note that with objects having more complex geometry, you can skip this step.
Next, run the cell fracture add-on and go to your second layer to begin working on the fractured cube.

First we are going to press <kbd>B</kbd>*to box select* the fractured cube, and select *add active* in the physics tab of the tool panel on the left. Press <kbd>T</kbd> if it's not open.

[image]

Next, add a plane below the cube and again go to the *tool panel>physics* since you need it to react to the fractured cube, click *add passive.*

[image]

Now if you play your animation your cube will just crumble and fall apart. To fix this, go to the *physics>rigid bodies* tab in the properties editor. You want to adjust the sensitivity margin next.
 Play with this until you like how the animation looks.

[image]

If for some reason, the cube crumbles and doesn't explode then select one of the fractured pieces, then box select the entire fractured object, and select *copy from active* in the physics settings in the *tool panel* and that should fix it. After following these steps you should be able to get something like this or better:[image]

Comment: YES!  Finally got it to work...thanks so much Timaroberts!!!!

Answer (score 6):

The cell fracture addon creates solid pieces to match the volume of the selected object. If you have failed trying the cell fracture addon you may have missed that it leaves your object intact and places all the new pieces onto the next layer, you need to change layers to see the pieces.

[image: broken cube]

After [enabling the addon](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/scripting/python/add_ons.html#enabling-and-disabling), there is a cell fracture button added to the tools region but you may find it easier to press space and type in cell. For a simple cube you will either want to subdivide multiple times or add a particle system then run the addon.

[image: cell fracture options panel]

[This blender cookie tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3GeP3YLZn5g3AiMpqzcpxa9aMRkllzjO) covers the cell fracture addon.

Comment: Yeah I tried all of this but for some reason the cube won't explode.  Here's the .blend file if that helps [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=935" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/935/)

Comment: @lakerice After you use Cell Fracture, you still need to pull the pieces apart. Cell Fracture > go to Layer 2 > select fractured pieces > turn on "Manipulate Center Points" > scale

Comment: Still can't get it to work.  Not sure if it's because I deleted the cube in layer 1 and moved the cube in layer 2 to layer 1?  That's what a few tutorials suggested.  I also noticed I can't turn on physics for some reason.

Comment: @lakerice the sample you uploaded is fractured into 88 pieces, you just need to separate them a bit.