# How do I cut up a 3D object into separate pieces

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

I have here a 3D piece of glass which I need to smash in Unity. Is there an easy way of cutting it in Blender into separate pieces? As you can see I have started cutting on one side but can't separate with both sides of the cut having faces and when Unity doesn't see a face it leaves a blank space.

[image]

Comment: You can try the *cell fracture addon*.

Comment: The recent answer about Cell Fracture - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45937/exploding-a-solid-object

Comment: cell fracture builds around the glass but it doesn't let you export it as separate pieces so it doesn't work in Unity

Comment: it makes a block around the glass but doesn't actually break it as an object at all

Answer (score 2):

Cell Fracture AddOn: [Cell Fracture AddOn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEo_9AopfoQ).  I'm pretty sure this is in Blender by default, but you may need to enable it in the User Preferences, then select the object, then bring up the Toolbar on the left of the 3D Window that you have the object selected in by pressing T, select Tools/Edit pane, then select Cell Fracture.

Or Fracture Modifier build (not an AddOn or plug-in) from Dennis Fassbaenders web site: [Fracture Modifier Blender Build](http://df-vfx.de/fracturemodifier/).  Explore that site too see if it's what you need.

Or do it all manually for complete control.

Comment: this doesn't break it as an object either

Answer (score 1):

You could use the loop cut tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) to cut the mesh. Then you can just select the diffrent parts (works best in face-select mode) and seperate them with <kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: I need it to break into non uniform pieces like broken glass

Comment: try the fracture addon: http://df-vfx.de/fracturemodifier/

Comment: any more ideas? I am splitting it into a hundred or more pieces manually at the mo there has to be a simpler way no?? HELP!!!